# Error While connecting to SQL server in android application using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sql-server-2008-r2

I am finding exception on `"conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);` Line.

```
public void query2() {
    Log.i("Android", " MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        System.out.println("*************inside class 1**************");
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

       // test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
        System.out.println("*************inside class 2**************");
        String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
                "DatabaseName=test;user=sa;password=sa1;";
        System.out.println("*************inside class 3**************");
        String username = "sa";
        String password = "sa1";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);
        Log.w("Connection", "open");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from titles");

        // Print the data to the console
        while (reset.next()) {
            Log.w("Data:", reset.getString(3));
            // Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2));

        }
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("Error connection", "" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My Log cat display:

```
  02-01 06:42:36.845: I/Android(1187):  MySQL Connect Example.
  02-01 06:42:39.365: I/System.out(1187): *************inside class 1**************
  02-01 06:42:40.843: I/System.out(1187): *************inside class 2**************
  02-01 06:42:42.396: I/System.out(1187): *************inside class 3**************
  02-01 06:42:45.220: D/dalvikvm(1187): GC_CONCURRENT freed 161K, 10% free 2606K/2888K, paused 74ms+72ms, total 233ms
  02-01 06:43:00.970: W/Error connection(1187): null
```

Comment: i am getting e.getMessage() = null

Comment: 02-01 06:42:36.845: I/Android(1187):  MySQL Connect Example.
02-01 06:42:39.365: I/System.out(1187): *************inside class 1**************
02-01 06:42:40.843: I/System.out(1187): *************inside class 2**************
02-01 06:42:42.396: I/System.out(1187): *************inside class 3**************
02-01 06:42:45.220: D/dalvikvm(1187): GC_CONCURRENT freed 161K, 10% free 2606K/2888K, paused 74ms+72ms, total 233ms
02-01 06:43:00.970: W/Error connection(1187): null

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string looks malformed. Also MySQL default port is 3306. Unless you changed the port number you should use 3306. Pull the username and passwrod out of the Connstring. If you are using

```
getConnection (ConnStr, User, Password)
```

you don't need to set it in the conn string as you're passing it in the call.

Try this conn string which is bare bones but should connect. Make sure to use getConnection and pass in username/password

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:3306/test
```

If this does not work you will need to output more info and errors to Logcat. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) to understand how to use Logcat. You don't have any error messages in Logcat in your Post, only Info and Warning

Comment: Fair enough, use 1433. But the JTDS conn string syntax remains the same

Comment: Please help me i am not yet getting propar solution

Comment: You have to help us by providing additional error messaging. You have not given us the error you receive when trying to connect. There is a way to get that error message(s) into Logcat. Does the database say anything about connections being refused or connection attempts